# jQuery.ajax() parsererror

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parse-error

when i try to get JSON from http://api-v3.deezer.com/1.0/search/album/?q=beethoven&index=2&nb_items=2&output=json with:

```
(jQuery 1.6.2)

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (result) {
        alert("SUCCESS!!!");
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.statusText);
        alert(xhr.responseText);
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
    }
});
```

I get: `parsererror; 200; undefined; jquery162******************** was not called`

but with the JSON from http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=beethoven&callback=?&count=5 works fine.
Both are valid JSON formats. So what is this error about?

**[UPDATE]**

@3ngima, i have implemented this in asp.net, it works fine:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "WebService.asmx/GetTestData",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result.d);
    }
});
```

WebService.asmx:

```
[WebMethod]
public string GetTestData()
{
    try
    {
        var req = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("http://api-v3.deezer.com/1.0/search/album/?q=beethoven&index=2&nb_items=2&output=json");
        using (var resp = req.GetResponse())
        using (var stream = resp.GetResponseStream())
        using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
        return reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    catch (Exception) { return null; }
}
```

Comment: You can refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/29485687/3126639.
The async: false is important.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's because you're telling jQuery that you're expecting [JSON-P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP), not [JSON](http://json.org), back. But the return is JSON. JSON-P is horribly mis-named, named in a way that causes no end of confusion. It's a *convention* for conveying data to a function via a `script` tag. In contrast, JSON is a data format.

Example of JSON:

```
{"foo": "bar"}
```

Example of JSON-P:

```
yourCallback({"foo": "bar"});
```

JSON-P works because JSON is a subset of JavaScript literal notation. JSON-P is nothing more than a promise that if you tell the service you're calling what function name to call back (usually by putting a `callback` parameter in the request), the response will be in the form of `functionname(data)`, where `data` will be "JSON" (or more usually, a JavaScript literal, which may not be the *quite* the same thing). You're meant to use a JSON-P URL in a `script` tag's `src` (which jQuery does for you), to get around the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) which prevents ajax requests from requesting data from origins other than the document they originate in (unless the server supports [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) and your browser does as well).

Comment: Btw it seems this API does not support JSON-P (I only found this: http://www.deezer.com/en/developers/simpleapi).

Comment: Oh, i see. hmmm, if i put the datatype to json it doenst work too.

Comment: @Stack: It wouldn't do, unless the page you're calling it from is on `api-v3.deezer.com`, because of the SOP (see link in answer).

Answer (score 0):

in case the server does not support the `cross domain` request you can:

1. create a server side proxy
2. do ajax request to your proxy which in turn will get `json` from the service, and
3. return the response and then you can manipulate it ...

in php you can do it like this

proxy.php contains the following code

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['geturl']) and !empty($_POST['geturl'])) {
$data = file_get_contents($_POST['geturl']);
print $data;
}

?>
```

and you do the ajax request to you proxy like this

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$("#btn").click(function(){
alert("abt to do ajax");

$.ajax({
url:'proxy.php',
type:"POST",
data:{geturl:'http://api-v3.deezer.com/1.0/search/album/?q=beethoven&index=2&nb_items=2&output=json'},
success:function(data){
alert("success");
alert(data);
}    
});    
});   
});
</script>
```

tried and tested i get the json response back...

Answer (score 0):

At last i have found the solution. First of all, the webmethods in a webservice or page doesn't work for me, it always returns xml, in local works fine but in a service provider like godaddy it doesn't.

My solution was to create an `.ahsx`, a handler in .net and wrap the content with the jquery callback function that pass the jsonp, and it works .

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class HandlerExterno : IHttpHandler
{
    string respuesta = string.Empty;

    public void ProcessRequest ( HttpContext context )
    {


       string  calls=  context.Request.QueryString["callback"].ToString();

         respuesta = ObtenerRespuesta();
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        context.Response.Write( calls +"("+    respuesta +")");
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    private string ObtenerRespuesta ()
    {



        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer j = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();


        Employee[] e = new Employee[2];
        e[0] = new Employee();
        e[0].Name = "Ajay Singh";
        e[0].Company = "Birlasoft Ltd.";
        e[0].Address = "LosAngeles California";
        e[0].Phone = "1204675";
        e[0].Country = "US";
        e[1] = new Employee();
        e[1].Name = "Ajay Singh";
        e[1].Company = "Birlasoft Ltd.";
        e[1].Address = "D-195 Sector Noida";
        e[1].Phone = "1204675";
        e[1].Country = "India";

        respuesta = j.Serialize(e).ToString();
        return respuesta;

    }

}//class

public class Employee
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Company
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Address
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Phone
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Country
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

And here is the call with jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        // url: "http://www.wookmark.com/api/json",
        url: 'http://www.gjgsoftware.com/handlerexterno.ashx',
        dataType: "jsonp",


        success: function (data) {
            alert(data[0].Name);
        },
        error: function (data, status, errorThrown) {
            $('p').html(status + ">>  " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

and works perfectly

Gabriel