# Jquery XML Parse URL Issue

Tags: jquery, xml, picasa

I have been trying to pull in the names of the albums from picasa using the jquery xml parser. However when I use the "https://picasaweb.google.com" link the function doesn't work. Any clues as to what I am doing wrong?

```
 <script>
      $(document).ready(function()
    {
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/userID?kind=album&access=visible",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: parseXml
      });
    });

    function parseXml(xml)
    {
      $(xml).find('entry').each(function()
      {
       $("#output").append($(this).find('title').text() + "<br />");
      });
    }
    </script>


    <div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do the cross domain requests (if the server supports it) by

setting [`crossDomain:true`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)  (added in jquery 1.5)

and/or

by setting `dataType:'jsonp'`

or else you can create a server side proxy to which you can do the ajax request that proxy will in turn get data from the web service and retyrn the response

see this answer for creating and getting data back in PHP
[jQuery.ajax() parsererror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643838/jquery-ajax-parsererror/6643993#6643993)

Answer (score 3):

For those interested below is the corrected code

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function()
{
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/userID?kind=album&access=visible',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: parseXml
  });
});

function parseXml(xml)
{
  $(xml).find('entry').each(function()
  {
   $("#output").append($(this).find('title').text() + "<br />");
  });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access data on a [different origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) without using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) and the browser is putting security walls in front of you.