# getJSON external URL - output not appearing in div

Tags: javascript, html, json, getjson

Nothing appears in the content.

```
jQuery(function($) {

$.getJSON('http://countdown.tfl.gov.uk/stopBoard/55191')
    .success(function(response) {
        var $content = $('#content')
            .html(response.arrivals[0].destination);

        });
});
```

DIV Section:

```
 <div id="content"></div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zax2n/1/

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://countdown.tfl.gov.uk/stopBoard/55191. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.`
Always check your console for errors.

Comment: This is answered here as well along with explanation / examples: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19821851/3535297

Comment: Basically you can't access resources outside your own server, it's a known issue in web development (there are some work arounds though).

Comment: you have to use jsonp or do a cross-origin request. Ofc server has to support one of them.

Comment: I have no clue how to retrieve and manipulate data using JS. Any examples?

Comment: Update - Added the AJAX part and still nothing http://jsfiddle.net/W6new/5/

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other comments, nothing is happening because you're receiving the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header error. However, there is an easy way around this: JSONP.

```
$.ajax("http://countdown.tfl.gov.uk/stopBoard/55191", {
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(data, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(textStatus);
    }
});
```

By specifying through the longhand `$.ajax()` method that you are requesting JSONP, you'll get your JSON object in response.

Check out this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rLwwL/). Open your console and you'll see that everything is working, but there's a parse error (the JSON you're getting back might be malformed).

Comment: Tried it again using http://jsfiddle.net/W6new/5/ (part of your code) - still nothing.

Comment: You're missing a `+` on line 10. Needs to be:

`$("body").append('<div>' + $routeid + $routename + '</div>');`

You should get the alert error.

Comment: Reported the malformed JSON output. How come it works if I use PHP and not JS?

Comment: I'm not sure, TBH. But that's a great, specific question to ask the community now that you know to fetch it with ajax.

Comment: It appears as valid here - http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/  Ref. http://countdown.tfl.gov.uk/stopBoard/55191

Comment: @CodyRaspien I did some digging and it probably has to do with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643838/jquery-ajax-parsererror).